# İnstagram clone app with Kotlin comments error

Tags: android, kotlin

My İnstagram Clone App is working normally.But İf you clicked comments and going to comments fragment and app is crashed. I am looking logcat and errors say Picasso isnt working. Please help thank you.

```
  private fun getUserInfo(imageProfile: CircleImageView, userNameTv: TextView, publisher: String) {
    val userREf = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Users").child(publisher)
    userREf.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
            if(p0.exists()){
                val user = p0.getValue(User::class.java)
    Picasso.get().load(user!!.getImage()).placeholder(R.drawable.profile).into(imageProfile)
                userNameTv.text= user!!.getUsername()
            }
        }
        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }
    })
 }
```

Comment: post your logcat also

Comment: what is `user!!.getImage()` is returning?

Comment: Or you can on picasso logging and check more specific errors

Comment: user!!.getImage() user profile photo

Comment: are you sure this is not null or not returning any other wrong url?

Comment: yes ı am sure .

Comment: path must not be empty clearly shows that your `user!!.getImage()` is empty

Comment: `Log.d("myUrl", user!!.getImage())` use this and seach myUrl in Debug log and see the value

Comment: okay ı am trying

Comment: I noticed that note. İf comments publisher has profile photo app is not crashed , not problem. But publisher hasnt profile photo app is crashed. Why about this problem ?

Comment: check out my answer

Comment: Log.d("myUrl", user!!.getImage()) where write this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this code

```
if (user!!.getImage().isEmpty()) {
   Picasso.get().load(R.drawable.profile).into(imageProfile) //if publisher hasnt profile photo it will load from drawable
}
else {
  Picasso.get().load(user!!.getImage()).placeholder(R.drawable.profile).into(imageProfile)
```